# Convex Function Help and Counterxample

Tags: optimization, terminology, examples-counterexamples, convex-optimization

Given $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and increasing. Show that $(f \circ g): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$  is convex.

I had no problem proving the previous statement but now I need to use it to show that $h(\mathbf x)=\exp(\mathbf x^T \mathbf x)$ is convex and then show was as counterexample that $k(\mathbf x)=\exp(-\mathbf x^T \mathbf x)$ is not.

I don't know what $\exp(\mathbf x^T \mathbf x)$ means... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, and $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}$ is the dot product, which will give you a non-negative number. $\exp(y)$ is just the exponential $e^y$.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'm trying to make h(x) a composition function so I can use the results I just found in the proof, would it make sense to have f(x)=$e^x$ and g(x)=(**x** $^T$ **x**) so when I take the composition f(g(x)) I get h(x)??

Comment: Yes, that looks good.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf{x}=(x_i)_i$ is a (column) vector, then $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}=\sum_ix_i^2$ gives you the scalar product of $\mathbf{x}$ with itself (and thus its $2$-norm squared).

$\exp$ is simply the exponential function, $\exp(t)=e^t$.

Comment: Thank you! If there was a negative sign in front of the $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$ so it would be $-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$. Is it correct that the summation would then be $\sum_i-x_i^2$. So the it would result in a negative result?

Comment: Yes, it is $-(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x})$, and the element in the brackets is simply a number.